# How to backup ePubs and pdfs to iCloud

Tags: icloud, pdf, books, epub

Is it even possible? I have hundreds of books in all these formats sitting in my iBooks library on my Mac. Now, I do notice that I can safely delete my iBooks (purchased off iBooks Store) from my local library and the titles still show in my list, with a little cloud icon saying the book is still available for download off iCloud. Is there any way to do the same for books in other formats, i.e. PDF and ePub? I would love to move my entire library to iCloud and free up local space if this were possible.

Answer (score 1):

Just drag your files ePub and PDF files in your iBooks and it will be synced through your devices(provided they use the same iCloud ID). ePubs should appear under books and PDF will have a category of their own.